# Target all .Net versions of .net5 or higher in msbuild condition

Tags: .net, msbuild

When building a application with multiple target Frameworks .Net 6.0 and .Net Framework 4.7.2 (`<TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net472</TargetFrameworks>`) application you can specify conditions for msbuild in a project or target file like that:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0'"> Something </ItemGroup>
OR
<Target Name="MyUniqueTarget213243" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Message for .net Framework" Condition="$(TargetFramework)' == 'net472'" />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Message for .net 6 and higher" Condition="$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0'" />
</Target>
```

This works good for the specific versions of .net Framework 4.7.2 and .Net 6.0, but it'll break for .net 8 or .net Framework 3.5.

As the old framework will always be net472, that's no problem, but the newer one will be updated anytime to 8.0 or 10.0 or whatever.

**Can I set a condition to target all versions of .Net 5 and above (like net5.0, net6.0, net8.0 or net8.3)[If there will ever be 8.3], but not .net core(netcoreapp2.1) or .net Framework 4.7.2(net472)**

What I tried so far:

```
<Message Importance="high" Text="Output Substring+Trim: '$(TargetFramework.Substring(3).Trim(`1234567890`))'" />
<Message Condition="'$(TargetFramework.Substring(3).Trim(`1234567890`))' == '.'" Importance="high" Text="ShowsIfConditionIsTrue" />
<!---> error MSB4184: The expression """.Substring(3)" cannot be evaluated. startIndex cannot be larger than length of string. Msbuild seems to do a build where TargetFramework is ''-->
<!---> Can be paired with condition like '$(TargetFramework)' != '', but complicated and seems stupid-->
<Message Importance="high" Text="Output Trim: '$(TargetFramework.Trim(`net1234567890`))'" />
<Message Condition="'$(TargetFramework.Trim(`net1234567890`))' == '.'" Importance="high" Text="ShowsIfConditionIsTrue" />
<!---> unreliable-->
<Message Condition="'$(TargetFramework.Contains(`net6`))' == true" Importance="high" Text="ShowsIfConditionIsTrue" />
<!---> checks only one framework-->
<Message Condition="'$(new string[]{`net5.0`, `net6.0`}.Contains(TargetFramework))' == true" Importance="high" Text="ShowsIfConditionIsTrue" />
<!---> error: new string[]{`net5.0`, `net6.0`}.Contains(TargetFramework) cannot be evaluated-->
<!--  -> only fixed values-->
<Message Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net472'" Importance="high" Text="ShowsIfConditionIsTrue" />
<!---> may target net45 or netcoreSomething or whatever-->
```

Comment: The code block following "What I tried so far:" is a mix of pseudo code and error messages. Can you show your actual code?

Comment: @JonathanDodds If you want to. I tried to reduce the mess by only showing the condition. Now it's only Code and Comments. More readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment of Xenohon, how about something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <IsUnifiedNETVersion>$([MSBuild]::VersionGreaterThanOrEquals('$([MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkVersion('$(TargetFramework)'))','6.0'))</IsUnifiedNETVersion>
    <MessageText Condition="$(IsUnifiedNETVersion) == 'true'">NET 6 or Higher is beeing used</MessageText>
    <MessageText Condition="$(IsUnifiedNETVersion) == 'false'">NET472 is beeing used</MessageText>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="MyTarget" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="IsNet6OrHigher = $(IsUnifiedNETVersion)" />
    <Message Importance="High" Text="$(MessageText)" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET 6 is mostly forward-compatible: binaries compiled for .NET 6 will work* on the .NET 8 runtime. You don't have to explicitly target .NET 8 to support it.

For example, `Newtonsoft.Json` only explicitly supports .NET 6([csproj](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/55a7204f9b9546aa07145591d42046d509176ad4/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.csproj#L3)), but it can run on .NET 8 nonetheless, as indicated on NuGet.
[image: Image of supported .NET versions of Newtonsoft.Json]

*: If the binary is affected by the numerous binary-breaking changes in .NET 8 and .NET 7, it might not run. But the likelihood is small.

Comment: That's good to know, but i asked for a way to check for versions of net5 (or net6) or higher. I expected them to be compatible, that's why I want that condition. Something like `Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net' && '$(TargetFramework->%Version)' > 5"`

Comment: Ah I see. You can use the [property functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2022#msbuild-version-comparison-functions) for that. For example, to check if `$(TargetFramework)` is compatible with `net5.0`, use `$([MSBuild]::IsTargetFrameworkCompatible('net5.0', $(TargetFramework)))`